# How to make Intellij Idea remember my ssh key coupling to Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh

My sys is Ubunty.
The problem is that after I renewed licence for Intellij Ultimate, every time after relogin it looses ssh key coupling to my git. I mean if I type ssh -T git@github.com, it says

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

ok, after that I go and evaluate ssh agent by typing:

> eval $(ssh-agent -s)

then i add my key

> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa2

and after that everything works fine. But - after relogin  I have to it again.
Help me to figer out what to do in order Intellij remember configuration. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated SSH key and added it to your GitHub account?
The process is documented here and it works for me when connecting IntelliJ to my GitHub account.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504--Solved-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase

Also check out GitHub's SSH key generation guidelines - https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: I forgot to mention I am running this on Windows, not on Ubuntu, however that should not make much difference given that IntelliJ supports the feature.

Comment: Yes, keys are generated, added to git. The thing is that it works fine from the terminal at any time. Problem is within Intellij 100% and I can't solve it so far...